# Hellocharts android library not rendering chart when there is a single value or when y axis values are same

Tags: java, android, charts

Am using hellochart library
https://github.com/lecho/hellocharts-android to show a linechart in my app.

When i try to generate  the graph with a single value, it is just showing an empty graph (It is supposed to show a single dot in the graph indicating the value right?).

The problem also persists if the first and second y axis value is same (When there is just 2 values).

Any ideas why this weird problem occurs?

The code am using is given below

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        List<String> datelist = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<Float> weightlist = new ArrayList<Float>();
        datelist.add("12/Apr/2020");
        weightlist.add(72f);
        datelist.add("13/Apr/2020");
        weightlist.add(72f);

        LineChartView chart = findViewById(R.id.chart);

        List<AxisValue> axisValues = new ArrayList<AxisValue>();
        List<PointValue> values = new ArrayList<PointValue>();
        for (int i = 0; i < datelist.size(); ++i) {
            values.add(new PointValue(i, weightlist.get(i)));
            axisValues.add(new AxisValue(i).setLabel(datelist.get(i)));
        }

        Line line = new Line(values).setColor(Color.BLUE).setCubic(false);
        line.setHasLabels(true);
        List<Line> lines = new ArrayList<Line>();
        lines.add(line);

        LineChartData data = new LineChartData();
        data.setLines(lines);

        data.setAxisXBottom(new Axis(axisValues));
        data.setAxisYLeft(new Axis());

        chart.setLineChartData(data);


    }
}
```

Comment: The expected behavior depends on the chart type you are using and the exact data.
Please, can you specify the chart type and the data? Or simply share the chart configuration code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the the solution i finally found, To set the viewport manually.

```
        float ymax= maxyvalue +10f;
        final Viewport v = new Viewport(chart.getMaximumViewport());
        v.top =ymax; //max value
        v.bottom = 0f;  //min value
        chart.setMaximumViewport(v);
        chart.setCurrentViewport(v);
```

Hope it will help somebody in future.